# Slim Jquery Mobile UI (without page role)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I love the new design of Jquery UIs (the mobile one). So, even on a project that is not targeted to  mobile environment I want to have some elements from the library.

The problem is that the lib needs to instantiate itself from a page scope (`data-role=page`) and therefore alter dozen root styles, events and aspects of the entire page. I just want some buttons, forms and colapsable.. in specific pages.

Some of the behaviour can be overwritten within `mobileinit` [event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html) but the most part cant be stopped.

**So, the question is:** is there a simple way to instantiate jquery-mobile ui elements or to have a cleaner init page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [JQueryMobile Download Builder [Alpha Release]](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) to build a custom version of JQM. The Builder handles dependencies. So you should be able to select the `Widgets` and `Forms` elements you can incorporate without the `Page Creation` and `Page Section` modules.

Answer (score 1):

According to the JQM docs the page structure is a [convention not a requirement](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) (scroll to the bottom), so you don't need to have `div`s with the `data-role="page"` attribute. 
In addition as @NirmalPatel mentioned you can use the new [Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) to just download the components that you want.

Comment: yes they say that but do not mention how to accomplish. BTW, @NirmalPatel pointed to the right direction but I still can't initiate any elemente (now without page triggers) as JQM docs do not teach how to manually apply the changes. Seems like a overlooked feature.

Comment: You just leave out those `elements` from your markup. As for how to manualy update an element it depends on what element it is but it should be something along the lines of `$("#mybutton").button();` or `$("#mylistview").listview();`.